# Find the nearest element in array based on value but not when the value exceeded the nearest in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to find the nearest element in an array based on a value but want the nearest greater than or equal to the value... for example in this array [3000, 5000, 8000], when I search for 3000 and below it should return 3000 but when I search for 3001, it should return 5000.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
let array = [3000, 5000, 8000];

private closestNumArray(array, num) {
    var x = array.reduce(function(min, max) {
      return (Math.abs(max - num) < Math.abs(min - num) ? max : min);
    });

    return x;
  }

closesNumArray(array, 3001) // returns 3000
```

I want to  it to return 5000 or the nearest next element based on value but it return 3000

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the array is sorted a simple while loop is all that is required. If we run over the end of the array (because `val` is too large) we return the last value in the array.

```js
let array = [3000, 5000, 8000];

const closestNumArray = function(array, val) {
  i = 0;
  while (i < array.length && array[i] < val) i++;
  return array[i] || array[i-1];
}

console.log(closestNumArray(array, 2999));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 3000));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 3001));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 5000));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 5001));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 8000));
console.log(closestNumArray(array, 8001));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is lower_bound of the element. find the position of the element where your target element will be inserted in the sorted array.

```js
let array = [3000, 5000, 8000];


array.sort();

console.log(array)

let target = 3001;
let ans = -1;
for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 if(target<=array[i]){
  ans = i;
        break;
 }
}

if(ans == -1){
 console.log("Element not found");
}
else{
 console.log(array[ans]); // -1 for when all elements are smaller than target
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to have the array sorted.

```js
(function(array, num) { 
   return array.reduce(function(nearest, current) { 
                          return (Math.abs(current - num) < Math.abs(nearest - num))  
                                     ? current : nearest; 
                       }); 
})([3000, 5000, 8000], 4001)
```

Returns 5000 because 4001 is nearer to 5000 than 3000.

I don't know why you named your arguments to the reduce function "min" and "max", that probably mislead you?

Comment: hi I just named it like that sorry for the confusion but what i need is the nearest next element. I i search for 3001 then it should return 5000 not 3000

Answer (score 0):

lower bound element in O(log(n)) using binary search.

```js
let array = [3000, 5000, 8000];

array.sort();

let target = 10000;

function lower_bound(array,target){
 let low = 0, high = array.length;

 while(low < high){

  let mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2);

  if(target<=array[mid]){
   high = mid;
  }
  else{
   low = mid+1;
  }
 }
 return low;
}

let index = lower_bound(array,target);
if(index == array.length){
 console.log('Element not found')
}
else{
 console.log(array[index]);
}
```